# Docusign REST API - PHP and add TABS

Tags: php, rest, api, docusignapi

I need to add more Tabs with the REST API Docusign. I use the example they give here : https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/quickstart-request-signature-email

But i don't know how to add more TABS like Initials?

```
$signHere = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\SignHere([ # DocuSign SignHere field/tab
    'document_id' => '1', 'page_number' => '1', 'recipient_id' => '1', 
    'tab_label' => 'SignHereTab', 'x_position' => '195', 'y_position' => '147'
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

just replace "SignHere" with "InitialHere" and everything else is the same if you want Initials.
Other tabs you can use are FullName, LastName, Date, Text, Number, FormulaTab, CheckBox, RadioGroup and Radio. All the same as this example just a different object.